# Equation in complex plane involving curvature and torsion of a space curve

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry

Given a space curve with non vanishing curvature $\kappa \neq 0$ and torsion $\tau$, and the relation $\kappa = \mu (\ \kappa^2 + \tau^2 )\ $, $\mu$ being a constant, I put $z = \kappa + i \tau$ and obtained the equation $$\cosh (\theta) = \mu r,$$ $r$ being the absolute value of $z$ and $\theta  = \dfrac{\tau}{\kappa}$

My intuition in the complex plane is quite iffy. What is the image of the above equation and what can this tell me about the curvature and torsion values possible?Is the above equation actually useful at all??

Comment: Do you assume $\kappa$ and $\tau$ to be constant?

Comment: No. That would just restrict to a helix, right?

Comment: There are several details I don't understand. To start: 1. Are you given a space curve $\gamma$, and you want to know what properties of $\gamma$ can be deduced by looking at the parametric curve $z(t) = \kappa(t) + i\tau(t)$ in the complex plane? 2. Are you _assuming_ $\kappa = \mu(\kappa^{2} + \tau^{2})$, and you want to know the shape traced out by $z(t)$, with $(r, \theta)$ denoting polar coordinates in the $(\kappa, \tau)$ plane? 3. Is there a motivating problem that led you to introduce $z(t)$, or are you just curious?

Comment: @Andrew. 1. Yes I am given a space curve $\gamma$ and I am trying to glean some properties of it as you said. 2. Yes I am interested in what shape $z(t)$ traces with $(r,\theta)$ denoting polar coordinates as you rightly remarked.3 There is a motivating problem that led me to introduce $z$.

Answer (score 0):

I would check up algebra at first for correctness in special cases. When $\tau =0, $

$$ \mu\, \kappa = 1,  \theta = \infty, \cosh \infty = \mu \kappa =1 ?  $$

Comment: Yes. But I am not sure what you are hinting at.Can you elaborate?

Comment: I do not know how complex curvature of one parameter 3-space curves are formulated, did not hear of any .At first literature survey, googling may help. Among 2-D surfaces there are relations between particular selections of curvature( normal) and particular torsions ( geodesic torsion). I believe your intuition should conform to these as special cases,at same time obeying Frenet-Serret mobile triad relations.I like your basic proposal, hope you would succeed after some exposure to surface theory.

Comment: Thanks. I have not had any luck with googling or literature survey, possibly because search terms like "curvature complex torsion" are too broad. What sort of relations between normal curvature and geodesic torsion are you talking about??

Comment: Mohr's circle of curvatures.